# Why does my code stop inputting past a certain past?

Tags: python

#I am doing the celebrity dogs python coding task (AQA) and when the list of the dogs is printed past that point nothing else is being returned and it is supposed to ask to Select a Catorgory (1)Exercise, (2)Intelligence, (3)Friendliness, (4)Drool. Then the game is supposed to start so I think the problem may be around that part but I am still not sure. Any help would be much appreciated(im not a very experienced coder)

```
import random

def menu():
    print("[1] Play game")
    print("[2] Quit")

menu()

option = int(input("Enter your option: "))
# The program would register any option other than 1 or 3 as a quit, I fixed this by using >2 instead of !=3
# I added error checking

while option > 2:
    print("Option invalid")
    option = int(input("Enter your option: "))

if option == 1:
    pass

else:
    print("Thanks for using the code")
    quit()



def NumberOfCards():

    numberofcards = int(input("Please enter how many cards you would like to play with!(between 4 and 30 IT HAS TO BE EVEN): "))

    if numberofcards >= 4 and numberofcards <=30 and numberofcards % 2 == 0:

        print("value accepted")

        return numberofcards

    else:

        print("thats to low/high or odd try again ill return you to the main menu and you can try again!")

        """ This is a recursive call to the function. While it may work fine right now, it's generally not a good idea to use this technique in this way,
         as there is a limit to the amount of times a function can be called in itself. A better way would be to use a while loop to handle card number inputs.
         Try and think about how you would do this. """
        return NumberOfCards()



def Exercise(cards):

    values=[]

    for i in range(0,len(cards)):

        values.append(random.randint(1,5))

    return values


def Intelligence(cards):

    values=[]

    for i in range(0,len(cards)):

        values.append(random.randint(1,100))

    return values


def Friendliness(cards):

    values=[]

    for i in range(0,len(cards)):

        values.append(random.randint(1,10))

    return values



def Drool(cards):

    values=[]

    for i in range(0,len(cards)):
        values.append(random.randint(1,10))

    return values


def pilenumber():
    pass

def cardgeneration():
    pass

def DisplayCard(playercards):
    print(PlayerCards[0])



EachPlayerCards = int(NumberOfCards()/ 2)



ListOfDogs = ["Annie the Afgan Hound","Bertie the Boxer","Betty the Borzoi","Charlie the Chihuahua","Chaz the Cocker Spaniel",
              "Donald the Dalmatian","Dottie the Doberman","Fern the Fox Terrier","Frank the French Bulldog","George the Great Dane",
              "Gertie the Greyhound","Harry the Harrier","Ian the Irish Wolfhound","Juno the Jack Russell","Keith the Kerry Blue","Larry the Labrador","Marge the Maltese",
              "Max the Mutt","Nutty the Newfoundland","Olive the Old English Sheepdog","Peter the Pug","Poppy the Pekingese","Rosie the Rottweiler","Ruby the Retriever",
              "Sam the Springer Spaniel","Sukie the Saluki","Vernon the Vizsla","Whilma the West Highland Terrier","William the Whippet",
              "Yolande the Yorkshire Terrier"]



random.shuffle(ListOfDogs)

PlayerCards=[]
ComputerCards =[]

# I made the handing out cards more efficient

for card in range(EachPlayerCards):

    PlayerCards.append(ListOfDogs[card])
    ComputerCards.append(ListOfDogs[EachPlayerCards+card])

print(PlayerCards)
print(ComputerCards)


PlayerExercise=Exercise(PlayerCards)
PlayerIntelligence=Intelligence(PlayerCards)
PlayerFriendliness=Friendliness(PlayerCards)
PlayerDrool=Drool(PlayerCards)

# Does the same for ComputerCards

ComputerExercise=Exercise(ComputerCards)
ComputerIntelligence=Intelligence(ComputerCards)
ComputerFriendliness=Friendliness(ComputerCards)
ComputerDrool=Drool(ComputerCards)

def startgame():
    """ pilenumber hasn't been defined yet, but I get what you're trying to do """
    playerpile = pilenumber/2
    computerpile = pilenumber/2

    while true:
        print("you have :",playerpile,"cards :)")
        print("the computer has:",computerpile,"cards :)")
        print("your dogs name is :")
        print(random.choice(dogs))


        category=input("Please Select a Catorgory (1)Exercise, (2)Intelligence, (3)Friendliness, (4)Drool")

        y = 0

     
        if category == 1:
            print("you have chosen to compare Excercise")
            print("player :", playerexcercise,)
            print("Computer: ",computerexcercise,".")

            if ComputerExcercise > PlayerExcercise:
                        print("aw no you lost the : computer wins!")
                        playerpile = playerpile - 1
                        computerpile = computerpile + 1
                        print(PlayerExcercise)

                        
                        cardgeneration()
                        y = 1
            elif ComputerExcercise <= PlayerExcercise:
                        print("whooop you won : player wins!")
                        playerpile = playerpile + 1
                        computerpile = computerpile - 1
                        cardgeneration()
                        y = 1


        if category == 2:
            print("you have chosen to compare intelligence")
            print("player :", PlayerIntelligence,)
            print("Computer: ",ComputerIntelligence,".")

            if ComputerIntelligence > PlayerIntelligence:
                        print("aw no you lost the : computer wins!")
                        playerpile = playerpile - 1
                        computerpile = computerpile + 1
                        print(PlayerIntelligence)
                        cardgeneration()
                        y = 1
            elif ComputerIntelligence<= PlayerIntelligence:
                        print("whooop you won : player wins!")
                        playerpile = playerpile + 1
                        computerpile = computerpile - 1
                        cardgeneration()
                        y = 1


        if category == 3:
            print("you have chosen to compare friendliness")
            print("player :", PlayerFriendliness,)
            print("Computer: ",ComputerFriendliness,".")

            if ComputerFriendliness> PlayerFriendliness:
                        print("aw no you lost the : computer wins!")
                        playerpile = playerpile - 1
                        computerpile = computerpile + 1
                        print(PlayerFriendliness)
                        cardgeneration()
                        y = 1
            elif ComputerFriendliness <= PlayerFriendliness:
                        print("whooop you won : player wins!")
                        playerpile = playerpile + 1
                        computerpile = computerpile - 1
                        cardgeneration()
                        y = 1


        if category == 4:
            print("you have chosen to compare drool")
            print("player :", PlayerDrool,)
            print("Computer: ",ComputerDrool,".")

            if ComputerDrool > PlayerDrool:
                        print("aw no you lost the : computer wins!")
                        playerpile = playerpile - 1
                        computerpile = computerpile + 1
                        print(PlayerDrool)
                        cardgeneration()
                        y = 1
            elif ComputerDrool <= PlayerDrool:
                        print("whooop you won : player wins!")
                        playerpile = playerpile + 1
                        computerpile = computerpile - 1
                        cardgeneration()
                        y = 1
        if playerpile == pilenumber:
                    print("Player wins the game!")
                    leave()
        elif computerpile == pilenumber:
                    print("Computer wins the game!")


def leave():

    leave = input(("Would you like to play again or leave the game?"))

    if (leave == Y or leave == Y):
        print("Please come again!")
        raise SystemExit #Stops the whole code
    elif (leave == N or leave == n):
        print("Returning to main menu.")
        menu() #Returns to the main menu
```

Comment: Copy & paste all code isn't the best way to get help in here. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Here's my code, fix it for me"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling de function "startgame", that is the reason, just add "startgame()" at the end of the code(or whatever you think is better).

I also noticed that in the "leave" function you are not comparing the input with "y" just with "Y".